# Bash script to send mail only if command returns output

Tags: bash, sendmail

I'm trying to write a bash script that alerts me if some files are modified.
So I wrote this:

```
MYOUT=$(/usr/bin/find /home/public_html/ \( -iname "*.js" -o -iname "*.tpl" -o -iname "*.php" \) -mtime -1)
if [[ -n $? ]]
then
    mail -s "Hack attempt" my_mail@gmail.com <<<"$MYOUT"
fi
```

But it sends a mail even when no files are found.

What I'm missing?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you didn't expect this code to send an e-mail if no files were found. Can you explain what you think `$?` means and what you think `[[ -n $? ]]` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `/usr/bin/find` finds some file according to its arguments, two events occur: the return status is set to some value into the variable `$?` and a string is output into the variable `$MYOUT`, according to your code.

From your question "... script to send a mail only if command returns output", I can deduce you want to use the second method to decide to send a mail.

In that case, you have to change the condition of your test as below, checking the value of `$MYOUT` and not that of `$?`, putting the test into single square brackets:

```sh
MYOUT=$(/usr/bin/find /home/public_html/ \( -iname "*.js" -o -iname "*.tpl" -o -iname "*.php" \) -mtime -1)
if [ -n "$MYOUT" ]
then
    mail -s "Hack attempt" my_mail@gmail.com <<<"$MYOUT"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to check the exit status of the variable assignment.

```sh
if MYOUT=$(/usr/bin/find /home/public_html/ \( -iname "*.js" -o -iname "*.tpl" -o -iname "*.php" \) -mtime -1); then
  mail -s "Hack attempt" my_mail@gmail.com <<<"$MYOUT"
fi
```

Or, check the exit status like

```sh
MYOUT=$(/usr/bin/find /home/public_html/ \( -iname "*.js" -o -iname "*.tpl" -o -iname "*.php" \) -mtime -1)

case $? in
   0) mail -s "Hack attempt" my_mail@gmail.com <<<"$MYOUT";;
esac
```